# Is it secure to send username and password in plaintext from C# to Wordpress site over https

Tags: c#, wordpress, https

Is it secure to send username and password in plaintext from a C# app to Wordpress site over https?

I figure it is, since the password will be encrypted by https and will not be visible to middlemen.

Thats what happens when you use the Wordpress logjn form and type your password, am I right?

Comment: yes, It's secure

Comment: As long as the SSL-certificate isn't compromised, it is secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sites encrypt password before sending them over HTTP event when they use HTTPS. There is a js library that helps with that Crypto Js

But in general yes it is safe cause as you said HTTPS will keep the password safe from man in the middle

You can also find an example here (the example was not written by me):
https://codepen.io/gabrielizalo/pen/oLzaqx

```
// INIT
var myString   = "https://www.titanesmedellin.com/";
var myPassword = "myPassword";


// PROCESS
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(myString, myPassword);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, myPassword);
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Comment: CryptoJS is no longer maintained. Take a look of another JS Crypto Libraries in this list: [Awesome JavaScript Crypto Libraries](https://github.com/gabrielizalo/Awesome-JavaScript-Crypto-Libraries).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a valid security encryption certificate (SSL or TLS) you should be fine I think.

Comment: Don't use SSL by the way

Comment: My site uses https using certificates from letsencrypt.com - is that secure enough?

Comment: Can't really say but looking at the website, it seems legit but do not take my word for it :)

Comment: It seems to have regular updates and a passionate development team so I would be comfortable using it myself, remember to donate though!